# What is the difference between this initialization methods?

Tags: c#, .net

What is the difference between this two codes?

```
class SomeClass   
{   

   SomeType val = new SomeType();   

}
```

and

```
class SomeClass  
{      
   SomeType val;   

   SomeClass()   
   {   
       val = new SomeType();   
   }   

}
```

Which method is preferd?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is *almost* not difference between them. The assignment of the field will happen within the constructor in both cases. There is a difference in how this happpens in relation to base class constructors though. Take the following code:

```
class Base
{
    public Base()
    {

    }
}

class One : Base
{
    string test = "text";
}

class Two : Base
{
    string test;
    public Two()
    {
        test = "text";
    }
}
```

In this case the base class constructor will be invoked *after* the field assignment in the class `One`, but *before* the assignment in class `Two`.

Answer (score 2):

The first version allows you to define multiple constructors without having to remember to put the `= new SomeType()` in each one.