# Whats the difference between these two initialization methods for a class member in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, initialization

Whats the difference between these two initialization methods for `obj`?  I've seen both of these, but know know if there is an appropriate time to use one vs the other.  I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475420/what-is-the-difference-between-this-initialization-methods) which covers C#, but not sure if the same applies to VB.Net.

```
Public Class Class1
   Sub New()
   End Sub

   Dim obj As New Object
End Class
```

vs

```
Public Class Class1
   Sub New()
      obj=New Object
   End Sub

   Dim obj As Object
End Class
```

My apologies ahead of time if this a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, there is no difference.  The main difference would be if your constructor does other operations -

In that case, the inline initialization  (`Dim obj As New Object`) will occur prior to any code inside the constructor.  Putting the initialization in the constructor lets you choose the order of initialization.

Answer (score 2):

Virtually nothing is different about these samples.  In both cases you get the following order of operations

- Constructor for `Class1` is called
- Base constructor (`Object` in this case) is called
- Field `obj` is assigned a value

In all likely hood it results in identical IL being generated.

Answer (score 1):

Your first version is "declarative". The advantages of it are:

1. It is easier to see how an field as initialized, as you don't have to look for it in the constructor.
2. If you have multiple constructors you don't need to repeat yourself.

Your first version is "imperative". The advantages of it are:

1. You control exactly when it gets created.
2. You can have different versions for each constructor.

I personally default to declarative style code whenever possible.